# Multiple Splitters in WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, gridsplitter

I have a wpf window in which there are several group boxes which are added based on user requirements. I want to expand any of the group box to see its entire contents. Attached image represents the layout.

[image]

I have tried to use Grid splitter but it splits the grid in exact two portions, where I want to split it in dynamic numbers(based on the number of groupboxes). How could I design a layout which could support this feature.

I have tried to add multiple Grid splitter controls in their separate columns, but then they expand their own columns by eating up the spaces of the group boxes which is something not required.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is that I'll create an interface that your current `TrackViewModel` then create a `ViewModel` for that `GridSplitter` and let both classes implement `ITrackItem`

```
public class GridSplitterViewModel : ITrackItem
{
  // Code omitted...
}

public class TrackViewModel : ITrackItem
{
  // Code omitted...
}

public interface ITrackItem
{
  // Whatever properties that you may need.
  public Type ItemType { get; }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
   public MainViewModel()
   {
     // Made it simple but the idea is here..
     Tracks = new ObservableCollection<ITrackItem>(GetSomethingFromTheDatabaseMaybe());
     Tracks.Insert(1, new GridSplitterViewModel());
     Tracks.Insert(3, new GridSplitterViewModel());
   }

  // Rest of code omitted
}
```

And on your `XAML` you'll have to define `DataTriggers` for your `Items`. The idea here is that the `ViewModel` is still feeding the `UI` on what to show and the `UI` will handle the template changes based on `triggers`.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{ItemType}" Value="{x:Type GridSplitterViewModel}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GridSplitter/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
 </DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{ItemType}" Value="{x:Type TrackViewModel}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GroupBox Header="{Binding TrackName}" Width="400" 
               Height="{Binding ElementName=TabCharts,  Path= ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}}"  Margin="0 0 20 0">
                                                            <chart:CustomCharts></chart:CustomCharts>
            </GroupBox>
        </DataTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```